# How to assign a float to a int64_t

Tags: game-center, type-conversion

To upload a score to the game center, they require you to have a value which is of type `int64_t`.

Is there a way to simply convert my `float` to `int64_t`?

I have built my whole game around the score and i need an easy solution any ideas?

Comment: Do you need solution in the C language? How large can be your float (what is maximum value you want to convert)?

Comment: Objective-c, and numbers aren't to large they just have decimels

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a float to an int in Objective C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286756/how-do-i-convert-a-float-to-an-int-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at this. Someone else's answer (from http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/14839 )

> Every score has to be submitted as an int64. So you need to convert your float to match the setting of your leaderboard. So with a fixed 3
>   dp you need to multiply the float by 1000 to get the 3rd dp into the
>   int - then submit.
>
> so
>
> int64_t gcScore = (int64_t)(score * 1000.0f);
>
> gkscore.value = gcScore;
>
> With some rounding coming into play it is important to make sure what
>   gets submitted is what has also been shown to the player - we had some
>   problems of being 1 out on the GC and in game display at times - just
>   had to go through every display & conversion of the score values to
>   make sure they took care to display properly.
>
> All the changes to the leaderboard settings take a while it seems, and
>   submitted scores can often not show up for a while too. The Game
>   Center sandbox is pretty awful to be honest. Once you go live it is
>   better in responding to new scores, but you can't make any changes to
>   the leaderboard format so you have to persevere in the Sandbox to get
>   it right.

Answer (score 0):

If your floats are limited in size (less than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807), the conversion is

```
int64_t myInt = (int64_t) myFloat;
```

If you want to "save" decimals, you can scale results (multiply the float with 10 or 100):

```
int64_t myInt_scaled = (int64_t) (myFloat * 100.0);
```

Comment: No, int64_t is round number only; so to save several decimals you should scale your float.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cast the float into an int64_t and then check for overflow. This cast will truncate the number, i.e. 5.655 will become 5.

```
    try {
       score = (int64_t)floatScore;
    }
    catch(OverflowException e) {
       // Print error
    }
```