# Convert float to int in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

How can I convert a `float` to `int` while rounding up to the next integer? For example, 1.00001 would go to 2 and 1.9999 would go to 2.

Comment: Please rever here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286756/how-do-i-convert-a-float-to-an-int-in-objective-c

Comment: Why are you using float and not double? The other question, did you ever think about buying a book about the C language? Every heard of the functions floor, ceil and round?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
float myFloat = 3.333

// for nearest integer rounded up (3.333 -> 4):
int result = (int)ceilf(myFloat );

// for nearest integer (3.4999 -> 3, 3.5 -> 4):
int result = (int)roundf(myFloat );

// for nearest integer rounded down (3.999 -> 3):
int result = (int)floor(myFloat);

// For just an integer value (for which you don't care about accuracy) 
int result = (int)myFloat;
```

Answer (score 11):

Use [ceil](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/ceil/) function:

```
int intValue = (int)ceil(yourValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following C methods to get the int values from different dataTypes.

```
extern float ceilf(float);
extern double ceil(double);
extern long double ceill(long double);
```

These functions return float, double and long double respectively. But the job of these function is to get ceil of or floor of the argument. As in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Then you can cast the return value to desired type like.

```
int intVariable = (int)ceilf(floatValueToConvert);
```

Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if we have float value like 13.123 to convert it  into integer like 13

**Code**

float floatnumber=13.123;   //you can also use CGFloat instead of float

```
NSLog(@"%.f",floatnumber); // use for print in command prompt
```