# Make a customize UISlider value effect with int values not correct in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIView` which the `alpha` is `from 0.8 to 0.0` which stands for `100 - 0` (integer value)

When i swipe the screen left or right to make the increase or decrease the value. But i always miss some values with 4, like 14, 24 etc.

I know this might be the accuracy issue. But not sure how to solve this in a short time. thanks!

here is my code:

```
- (void) panFromLeftOrRight:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    //NSLog(@"%f",_valueView.alpha);
    if (_valueView.alpha > 0.8f) {
        _valueView.alpha = 0.8;
        return;
    }
    if (_valueView.alpha < 0.0) {
        _valueView.alpha = 0.0;
        return;
    }

    CGPoint point = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:_valueView];

    if ((point.x - _lastX) > 10) {
        _valueView.alpha -= 0.01;
        _lastX = point.x;
    }

    if ((point.x - _lastX) < -10) {
        _valueView.alpha += 0.01;
        _lastX = point.x;
    }

    if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        _lastX = 0.0;
    }

    float db = _valueView.alpha * 125.0f;
    NSLog(@"%f",db);
    NSLog(@"(%0.000f)",floor(db));
    _value.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f",db];
    //OR
    _value.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)db];

}
```

Here are the results of `db`:

```
2015-09-28 18:21:41.121 Rols[70691:2929217] 100.000000
2015-09-28 18:21:41.847 Rols[70691:2929217] 98.750000
2015-09-28 18:21:41.873 Rols[70691:2929217] 97.500008
2015-09-28 18:21:42.225 Rols[70691:2929217] 96.250008
2015-09-28 18:21:42.854 Rols[70691:2929217] 95.000008
2015-09-28 18:21:42.874 Rols[70691:2929217] 93.750008
2015-09-28 18:21:43.836 Rols[70691:2929217] 92.500008
2015-09-28 18:21:44.716 Rols[70691:2929217] 91.250008
```

So for `97.5`, if use

```
// for nearest integer (3.4999 -> 3, 3.5 -> 4):
int result = (int)roundf(myFloat );
```

i lost `97`.

And there's no `94` at all.

Please don't close this, it's not the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/8786962/291240

Comment: Why are you using a gesture recognizer **and** tracking the `x` position?  Why are you multiplying by `125.0`?  Why are you converting to `int` at all?

Comment: the question use this concept for side menu

Comment: Yes, just like UISlider, but the value should be countinuous integer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert float to int in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785468/convert-float-to-int-in-objective-c)

Comment: No it's no the same.

Comment: I dont know why people down vote this without a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are missing `4`, `14`, etc, is simply because of the numbers you've chosen:

```
0.01 * 125.0 = 1.25
0.02 * 125.0 = 2.50
0.03 * 125.0 = 3.75
0.04 * 125.0 = 5.00
0.05 * 125.0 = 6.25
...
0.10 * 125.0 = 12.50
0.11 * 125.0 = 13.75
0.12 * 125.0 = 15.00
```

There is nothing wrong with Objective-C's conversion from `float` to `int`, which is the same as the way C does it.

Answer (score 0):

I choose the step of alpha to `0.008` make it.
Change from:

```
_valueView.alpha -= 0.008;
```

To

```
_valueView.alpha -= 0.008;
```

And convert by the raw float by `(int)roundf(db)`